# Can't get a value by webscraping in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get Neymar's price from https://www.futbin.com/21/player/544/neymar-jr and I can't.
This is my code (I know it's awful, this is the first time I've tried to use webscraping, I'll take every advice I can get):`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

domain = 'https://www.futbin.com'
version = 21

player_ids = ['neymar-jr', 544]


def fetch_prices():

    url = "{0}/{1}/player/{2}/{3}".format(domain, version, player_ids[1], player_ids[0])
    response = requests.get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    price = html_soup.find_all('span', class_='price_big_right')
    return price


#<span id="ps-lowest-1" data-price="1,013,000">
# I'm supposed to get this data_price

fetch_prices()
```

[image: Printscreen of code inspection of the page]

Again, I'm trying to learn, and will take any help I can get, thanks in advance!
(Edit: Just found out that html_soup doesn't contain data-price="1,013,000" and stops at <span id="ps-lowest-1". Maybe that helps)

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: I get this: [<span class="price_big_right">
<span id="ps-lowest-1">-</span>
</span>, <span class="price_big_right">
<span id="xbox-lowest-1">-</span>
</span>, <span class="price_big_right">
<span id="pc-lowest-1">-</span>
</span>]

Comment: I'm trying to get the part after id=ps-lowest-1, but it doesn't even show up there

Comment: Did you check if page is loading content dynamically? i.e: JavaScript

Comment: how would I check that and what does that mean? sorry for the ignorance, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

The page loads content dynamically with javascript. So `request` won't work. You can try to use `selenium` instead, with a webdriver, to load the content before scraping.

You can download the ChromeDriver executable [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). And if you paste it in the same folder as your script you can run:

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# configure driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"  # IF NOT IN SAME FOLDER CHANGE THIS PATH
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

domain = 'https://www.futbin.com'
version = 21

player_ids = ['neymar-jr', 544]


def fetch_prices():

    url = "{0}/{1}/player/{2}/{3}".format(domain, version, player_ids[1], player_ids[0])
    driver.get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    price = html_soup.find_all('span', class_='price_big_right')
    return price

prices = fetch_prices()
```

And if you run:

```py
for item in prices:
    print(item.text)
```

It outputs:

```
1,009,000 
820,000 
1,083,000
```

Ps: loved that you are getting Neymar prices haha

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you can not load the whole page by requests.get because it does not render the JavaScript. In order to check it, you can open Dev Tools(F12 - in Chrome) and click "Console" open and type "Disable JavaScript" and refresh the page, after you will see what your web-scraper gets. I solved this problem by using alternative version by using [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). There is my code below:

```
In [86]: from selenium import webdriver
    ...: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ...: 
    ...: driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    ...: 
    ...: domain = 'https://www.futbin.com'
    ...: version = 21
    ...: 
    ...: player_ids = ['neymar-jr', 544]
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: def fetch_prices():
    ...: 
    ...:     url = "{0}/{1}/player/{2}/{3}".format(domain, version, player_ids[1], player_ids[0])
    ...:     driver.get(url)
    ...:     response = driver.page_source
    ...:     html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    ...:     price = html_soup.find_all('span', class_='price_big_right')
    ...:     return price
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: #<span id="ps-lowest-1" data-price="1,013,000">
    ...: # I'm supposed to get this data_price
    ...: 
    ...: fetch_prices()
```

and result:

```
Out[86]: 
[<span class="price_big_right">
 <span data-price="1,009,000" id="ps-lowest-1">1,009,000 <img alt="c" class="coins_icon_l_bin" src="https://cdn.futbin.com/design/img/coins_bin.png"/></span>
 </span>,
 <span class="price_big_right">
 <span data-price="815,000" id="xbox-lowest-1">815,000 <img alt="c" class="coins_icon_l_bin" src="https://cdn.futbin.com/design/img/coins_bin.png"/></span>
 </span>,
 <span class="price_big_right">
 <span data-price="1,088,000" id="pc-lowest-1">1,088,000 <img alt="c" class="coins_icon_l_bin" src="https://cdn.futbin.com/design/img/coins_bin.png"/></span>
 </span>]
```

Correct me, please, If`m wrong