# Can't web scrape nested tables using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request, python-requests-html

I've been trying to web scrape [this page](https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/licitacoes/490941800?ordenarPor=dataEmissao&direcao=asc) using `requests_html`, `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. Whenever I try to do it online (by using `requests.get` or `requests_html.HTMLSession()`) my code fails to find tags **inside the tables**, as in the example below:

```
r = requests.get(url=url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', class_='collapse-3')
print(div)
#None
```

This `div` is inside a section.

I've already tried to render the page:

```
with HTMLSession() as session:
    r = session.get(url=url, headers=headers)

r.html.render()

div = r.html.find('div.collapse-3')
print(div)
#None
```

But no success. It will only work if I download the HTML and load it.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296242/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup-wont-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030724/cant-get-a-value-by-webscraping-in-python) solutions using Selenium, but they do not solve the problem and I need a solution that does not rely on Selenium. As far as I can see, the problem is that the information that I need is inside an iterative table, which blocks me from accessing the information inside it.

Any advice is welcome! Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Get the data straight from the source (returned as JSON). Then read into pandas:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/licitacoes/item-licitacao/resultado'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'paginacaoSimples': 'false',
'tamanhoPagina': '1000',
'offset': '0',
'direcaoOrdenacao': 'asc',
'colunaOrdenacao': 'descricao',
'colunasSelecionadas': 'codigoItemCompra,descricao,descComplementarItemCompra,quantidade,valor,cpfCnpjVencedor,nome',
'skCompra': '205900728',
'_': '1633966570617'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload, verify=False).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['data'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
          codigoItemCompra  ...                         descComplementarItemCompra
0   1551260500022202100059  ...  ARTIGO PARA HIGIENE NO LEITO, TIPO LIMPADOR DE...
1   1551260500022202100004  ...  BANDAGEM ELÁSTICA, MATERIAL ALGODÃO, TIPO AUTO...
2   1551260500022202100003  ...  BANDAGEM ELÁSTICA, MATERIAL FITA MICROPOROSA, ...
3   1551260500022202100005  ...  BANDAGEM ELÁSTICA, MATERIAL NÃO TECIDO POROSO,...
4   1551260500022202100012  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
5   1551260500022202100010  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
6   1551260500022202100008  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
7   1551260500022202100017  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
8   1551260500022202100009  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
9   1551260500022202100016  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
10  1551260500022202100006  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
11  1551260500022202100014  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
12  1551260500022202100015  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
13  1551260500022202100013  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
14  1551260500022202100007  ...  BOLSA OSTOMIA, MATÉRIA PRIMA PLÁSTICO, APLICAÇ...
15  1551260500022202100018  ...  BOTA DE UNNA, COMPOSIÇÃO IMPREGNADA COM PASTA ...
16  1551260500022202100019  ...  CINTA ELÁSTICA, MATERIAL POLIÉSTER, TIPO ABDOM...
17  1551260500022202100020  ...  CLAMP INSTRUMENTAL, MODELO VASCULAR- BULLDOG, ...
18  1551260500022202100056  ...  COBERTURA, TIPO DE COBERTURA FILME TRANSPARENT...
19  1551260500022202100024  ...  COBERTURA, TIPO DE COBERTURA FILME TRANSPARENT...
20  1551260500022202100045  ...  CREME HIDRATANTE, COMPOSIÇÃO URÉIA E ÁCIDO LÁT...
21  1551260500022202100022  ...  CURATIVO, MATERIAL POLIURETANO, DIMENSÃO CERCA...
22  1551260500022202100035  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROCOLÓIDE, MATERIAL POLIURET...
23  1551260500022202100049  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROGEL, REVESTIMENTO REVESTID...
24  1551260500022202100038  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROPOLÍMERO, REVESTIMENTO REC...
25  1551260500022202100057  ...  CURATIVO, MATERIAL POLIÉSTER, REVESTIMENTO REV...
26  1551260500022202100040  ...  CURATIVO, MATERIAL ACETATO DE CELULOSE, REVEST...
27  1551260500022202100046  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROCOLÓIDE, MATERIAL POLIURET...
28  1551260500022202100034  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO MEMBRANA COM MICROPARTICULA DE ...
29  1551260500022202100047  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROCOLÓIDE, MATERIAL POLIURET...
30  1551260500022202100037  ...  CURATIVO, MATERIAL NÃO TECIDO, REVESTIMENTO PR...
31  1551260500022202100036  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROGEL, REVESTIMENTO REVESTID...
32  1551260500022202100025  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROGEL, MATERIAL POLIURETANO ...
33  1551260500022202100063  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROCOLÓIDE, MATERIAL POLIURET...
34  1551260500022202100051  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROGEL, REVESTIMENTO COM ALGI...
35  1551260500022202100041  ...  CURATIVO, MATERIAL POMADA, REVESTIMENTO C/ CAD...
36  1551260500022202100023  ...  CURATIVO, TIPO HIDROPOLÍMERO, MATERIAL POLIURE...
37  1551260500022202100039  ...  CURATIVO, MATERIAL NÃO TECIDO, REVESTIMENTO PR...
38  1551260500022202100029  ...  LENÇO DESCARTÁVEL, MATERIAL POLIPROPILENO E CE...
39  1551260500022202100031  ...  PELÍCULA ADESIVA, MATERIAL ADESIVO ACRÍLICO HI...
40  1551260500022202100001  ...  PELÍCULA ADESIVA, MATERIAL ADESIVO ACRÍLICO HI...
41  1551260500022202100002  ...  PLACA PERIOSTOMAL, MATERIAL DA PLACA HIDROCOLÓ...
42  1551260500022202100061  ...  POLIHEXANIDA, COMPOSIÇÃO ASSOCIADA À UNDECILAM...
43  1551260500022202100021  ...  PROTETOR CUTÂNEO, ASPECTO FÍSICO EM CREME, COM...
44  1551260500022202100033  ...  PROTETOR CUTÂNEO, ASPECTO FÍSICO EM CREME, COM...
45  1551260500022202100032  ...  PROTETOR CUTÂNEO, ASPECTO FÍSICO EM CREME, COM...
46  1551260500022202100055  ...  PROTETOR CUTÂNEO, ASPECTO FÍSICO EM PÓ, COMPOS...
47  1551260500022202100028  ...  PROTETOR CUTÂNEO, ASPECTO FÍSICO PLACA, MATERI...
48  1551260500022202100060  ...  PROTETOR CUTÂNEO, ASPECTO FÍSICO EM CREME, COM...
49  1551260500022202100054  ...  PROTETOR CUTÂNEO, ASPECTO FÍSICO EM SPRAY, COM...
50  1551260500022202100050  ...  SOLUÇÃO, TIPO À BASE DE BIGUANIDA (PHMB), CONC...
51  1551260500022202100027  ...  TERAPIA DE PRESSÃO NEGATIVA P/ FERIDAS, TIPO C...
52  1551260500022202100030  ...  ÁCIDOS GRAXOS ESSENCIAIS, COMPOSIÇÃO TCM, COMP...

[53 rows x 10 columns]
```

Without payload:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/licitacoes/item-licitacao/resultado?paginacaoSimples=false&tamanhoPagina=1000&offset=0&direcaoOrdenacao=asc&colunaOrdenacao=descricao&colunasSelecionadas=codigoItemCompra%2Cdescricao%2CdescComplementarItemCompra%2Cquantidade%2Cvalor%2CcpfCnpjVencedor%2Cnome&skCompra=205900728&_=1633967219449'

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload, verify=False).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['data'])
```

Comment: Do I need to provide the `payload` parameter?

Comment: Not if you encode it in the url

Comment: @Gabs, see edit

Comment: But how did you get that URL? It is not the same that I posted.

Comment: When you go to the site, look at the Dev Tools -> Network -> XHR

Comment: OK, but how do I get it without all this? I mean, how do I automate getting that url?

Comment: that is the url. It's not going to change. The parameters won't need to change either. The parameters are there to return how you want the data (Ie acending or descending order. The number of data points returned, etc.)  You don't need to automate anything to "get" it. Not quite sure what the issue is.

Comment: It is not the same URL. If I use the same URL you are using, I am redirected to another page with a different layout but the same information. Do you mind running your answer with this URL: https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/licitacoes/490941800?ordenarPor=dataEmissao&direcao=asc

Comment: are you only after that 1 table? or all 4 tables?

Comment: you are not going to get the table from the url you provided as it's rendered from that other url. You either need to use selenium, or like I suggested, use the url that gets the data directly for that table